# How to link NSTextView from nib to windowController?

Tags: ios, cocoa, nib, nstextview

I created an outlet property for NSTextView in an window controller file. I then created a separate window xib file with a NSTextView in it. How do I link the view object in the xib file to the outlet in the window controller file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the class of the file's owner in your xib file to be that of your window controller file, then the outlet will show up under the file's owner, and you can connect it from there.